# How to get two symbols as one with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on simple syntax highlighter for my own blog and faced a little problem...

For example I have a js code:

```
if (REDIRECTS_FOLLOWED >= REDIRECTS_FOLLOWED) {
    reject(new Error('Exceeded maximum redirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop ' +  response.headers.location))

    return false
}
```

In this line I need to highlite all punctuation like `(`, `>=`, `)`, `{`. Regex for this I'm using `/([\-\!\%\^\*\(\)\+\|\~\=\{\}\[\]\:\"\'<>\?\,\.\/]+)/`

The problem is that it gets only `=`, not `>=`.

Is it possible somehow to combine symbols in regex?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not escaping the angle brackets?

Comment: I do not think there is a problem with matching `>=`. Here is [your (a little trimmed from unnecessary escapes) regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WWbubb/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew dont know why but still doesn't work...

Comment: Is [this output](https://ideone.com/3MGYyp) expected?

Comment: Show us the php code.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is `([><]=|[-!%^*()+|~={}[\]:"'<>?,.\/])` in order to avoid matching `))` in one token

See the demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5NR04p/1)

*This is off-topic, but you javascript function's condition is likely to always be true.*

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. That was only for example, there a lot more of code.

Comment: Maybe add the relevant part of your PHP to your question.